# Need to add a column to a CSV that adds a number for each line of data (1,2,3,etc)

Tags: csv, vbscript

Need to append a CSV file to add a Column (Pkey) with an increment numeric starting from 1 for every line of data.  I prefer to have a VB script do this, but if theres an easier method I can run on a windows task scheduler I am open to anything.

I just need a script that creates a column in the CSV named "Pkey" and adds a increasing numeric +1 to every line of data, starting with 1.  This has to be unique counts all the way down to the final line of data.

Expected to have a column added with header Pkey, then number down the lines of data 1,2,3,4,5,etc till all lines of data have been numbered with a unique integer

Code that I currently use to pull the query into the CSV and save it, everytime I try to do the increment it breaks the script:

```
    Option Explicit

Dim TextExportPath  
Dim TextExportFile  
Dim db              
Dim cn              
Dim strCon          
Dim objFileSys     

db = "X:\VPP DATABASE\Pham.mdb"
TextExportPath = "X:\Scripts\FTP\QuickBase Sync\CustomerData\"
TextExportFile = NewFileName(TextExportPath)

Set objFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFileSys.FileExists("X:\Scripts\FTP\QuickBase Sync\CustomerData\MMD_Abacus.csv") Then
objFileSys.DeleteFile "X:\Scripts\FTP\QuickBase Sync\CustomerData\MMD_Abacus.csv"

End If


Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open _
    "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
    "Data Source =" & db

cn.Execute "SELECT * INTO [text;HDR=Yes;Database=" & TextExportPath & _
   "]." & TextExportFile & " FROM 83AFFNIGHT"


Function NewFileName(TextExportPath)
Dim fs
Dim NewFileTemp
Dim a, i

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


NewFileTemp = "MMD_Abacus" & ".csv"

a = fs.FileExists(TextExportPath & NewFileTemp)

NewFileName = NewFileTemp
End Function
```

So would I add something like this, or even create a separate vb script to run after this one?

```
Dim lines As New List(Of String)
Dim lineNumber = 1

Using parser As New TextFieldParser("TextFile1.txt") With {.Delimiters = {","}}
    Do Until parser.EndOfData
        Dim fields = parser.ReadFields()

        'Add quotes around the column that may be multiline.
        fields(1) = $"""{fields(1)}"""

        lines.Add(String.Join(",", fields) & "," & lineNumber)
        lineNumber += 1
    Loop
End Using

File.WriteAllLines("TextFile1.txt", lines)
```

Comment: vba<> vbscript, are you trying to write this through Excel or visual studios?

Comment: just a VB script, I have tried a bunch of different examples of code but none do exactly just that.

Comment: And thank you BigBen I understand, just been running into the wall trying to get this done by myself without asking for help, I finally gave up and asked for help lol

Comment: What wall were you running into. There are probably 50,000 examples on SO. Read a line. Add your column, increment, write the line.

Comment: and Scott I just write it out in notepad and do it that way, I have read that I could just do a macro in excel but I am creating the CSV through a vbscript and the VB writes the access query to the CSV

Comment: ill add my vbscript in the post current -- Noodles I am not great a vbscript and havent been able to get it to work :)

Comment: and Noodles [link]https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+a+new+column+to+csv+file+vb
only shows 4 hits :)

Comment: Don't use database functions. Use the FSO object. This uses STDIN rather than FSO (to avoid file opening) `Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream:OutP.WriteLine StrReverse(Inp.Readline):Loop` This reverses text on each line. Your search term is too specific - *how do I process a file line by line* is a better search term.

Comment: I will say the pulling of the data and saving it works perfectly fine and has for years on multiple systems, just recently needed to add an additional unique count for reporting purposes.  And I must say I'm more of a linux guy then windows, I loathe windows personally but this was the only way to get the data out of the pharmacy software.

Comment: Programmers mostly process lists (1/3rd to 1/2 of the time). Therefore we know when we see data that can be a list that a `Do … Loop` is probably the way to go. Trees require recursion and a list. Even if you keep it in a database, you do a `For Each … Next` on a recordset. I still have version 1 of Windows installed.

Comment: Consider  that Microsoft was the largest seller of Unix operating systems (Xenix). Wrote the AT&T Intel version of Unix. Then started selling DOS (which was written on Unix systems ie there are screenshots of Dos code in Vi) and gave up Unix. MS didn't use Windows or Dos internally, they used Xenix, until Win NT came out.

Comment: very nice history lesson there noodles ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using StdIn and StdOut means we don't have to write file handling code.

This starts at 1

```
    Count = 1
    Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
    Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        outp.writeline Count & vbtab & Line
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo MyScript.vbs < InputFile > Outputfile
```

Comment: That adds a tab delimited column (my preference since the early 90s), change `vbtab` to `","` for comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

> ... if theres an easier method I can run on a windows task scheduler I am open to anything.

Let's do PowerShell!

Make sure you're using [the 32-bit powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/starting-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6#starting-the-32-bit-version-of-windows-powershell) for this:

```
function Get-MSAccessTable {
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $filePath,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $tableName
)    
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$filePath;Persist Security Info=False")
    $cmd=$conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText="Select * from $tableName"
    $conn.open()
    $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
    $dt = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
    $dt.Load($rdr)
    $conn.close()
    $dt
}   

$TextExportPath = "X:\Scripts\FTP\QuickBase Sync\CustomerData"
$TextExportFile = "$TextExportPath\MMD_Abacus.csv"

$db = "X:\VPP DATABASE\Pham.mdb"
$data = Get-MSAccessTable -filePath $db -tableName "83AFFNIGHT"

$Global:seq = 1;
$data = $data | Select-Object <LIST COLUMNS HERE>, @{label = “PKey”; Expression = {$Global:seq;$Global:seq++ }}

Remove-Item -Path "X:\Scripts\FTP\QuickBase Sync\CustomerData\MMD_Abacus.csv"  
$data | Export-Csv -Path $TextExportFile -NoTypeInformation
```